# HTTP put request error when trying to upload images to aws S3 using React and Express

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3, axios

I'm trying to upload an image to aws s3 using React and express.
my React code is,

```
axios
 .put(putUrl, file[0], options)
 .then(() => {
          console.log("hello world");
 })
 .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
 })
```

this put Url was generated by express using this code before calling above code. And the file is the added files array,

```
generatePutUrl(Key, ContentType).then(putUrl => {
        res.send({putUrl});
        console.log({putUrl});
    }).catch(err => {
        res.send(err);
    });
```

options have this,

```
const options = {
            params: {
                Key: key,
                ContentType: contentType
            },
            headers: {
                'Content-Type':contentType
            }
        };
```

this key(ex: "example.png") have the image name and contentType is image type (ex: "image/png").
When I am trying to upload an image, it shows those two error messages and the image was not uploaded to S3 bucket.

```
Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:84)


PUT <generatedUrl> net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

this  is the value of generated S3 url.
when I am getting the generated URL from express server it's get request is working fine. but put request shows this erros.
what could be the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated the bucket policy like this. I've added **"s3:PutObject"** then the error was gone.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1624878606419",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1624878601700",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"
        }
    ]
}
```