# Error while uploading image to AWS s3 bucket using react-aws-s3-typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to implement [react-aws-s3-typescript][1]. As per the documentation, the usage is very simple. Here is my code -

```
function App() {async function handleImageChange(e: any) {
e.preventDefault();
await getCredentials();
const config = {
  bucketName: "bucketName",
  dirName: "/dirName/Images",
  region: "us-east-1",
  accessKeyId: localStorage.getItem("accessKey"),
  secretAccessKey: localStorage.getItem("secretKey")
};
const s3 = new ReactS3Client(config as IConfig);
let uploadedFile = e.target.files[0];
  return (
<div className="App">
  <input
    className="select-image-btn"
    type="file"
    onChange={(e) => handleImageChange(e)}
  />
</div>);}
```

the Error I am getting is -

```
POST https://bucketName.s3-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

and

```
TypeError: Failed to fetch
at ReactS3Client.<anonymous> (react-aws-s3.js:92:1)
at step (react-aws-s3.js:44:1)
at Object.next (react-aws-s3.js:25:1)
at react-aws-s3.js:19:1
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at __webpack_modules__../node_modules/react-aws-s3-typescript/dist/react-aws-s3.js.__awaiter (react-aws-s3.js:15:1)
at ReactS3Client.uploadFile (react-aws-s3.js:65:1)
at handleImageChange (App.tsx:27:1)
```

I am unable to understand the reason for the error shown in the console. Can anyone help me in understanding the problem?
[1]: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-aws-s3-typescript

Comment: Try without region in your config.

Comment: Here, as per the documentation in the package, the region is a mandatory parameter. Here is the url of the documentation - https://github.com/NimperX/react-aws-s3-typescript/blob/main/src/types.ts. You can see line number 8.

Comment: without region - it gives this error. `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')
    at buildUrl (Url.js:5:1)
    at exports.default (Url.js:17:1)
    at ReactS3Client.<anonymous> (react-aws-s3.js:79:1)
    at step (react-aws-s3.js:44:1)
    at Object.next (react-aws-s3.js:25:1)
    at react-aws-s3.js:19:1
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __webpack_modules__../node_modules/react-aws-s3-typescript/dist/react-aws-s3.js.__awaiter (react-aws-s3.js:15:1)
    at ReactS3Client.uploadFile (react-aws-s3.js:65:1)
    at handleImageChange (App.tsx:26:1)`

Comment: I was hoping the library code would infer that no region was necessary in the URL and create a URL such as `bucket.s3.amazonaws.com`. But it doesn't appear to. Anyhow, can you [dig](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dig) `bucketName.s3-us-east-1.amazonaws.com` from another machine?

Comment: I have tried the same project from another machine. The result is the same as what I had mentioned above.

Comment: Typically S3 endpoints are `{service}.{region}.amazonaws.com` (with a dot), not `{service}-{region}.amazonaws.com` (with a dash). The dash variants are legacy afaik. A quick DNS test of `s3-us-east-1.amazonaws.com` fails while `s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` succeeds. I see that you created a GitHub [issue](https://github.com/NimperX/react-aws-s3-typescript/issues/6) to track this. I wonder if the author of that library ever tested buckets in us-east-1 as well as ap-south-1.

Comment: Also, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68159923/http-put-request-error-when-trying-to-upload-images-to-aws-s3-using-react-and-ex), in case it's helpful.

Comment: I have checked that for all regions other than Canada, the settings of the url as per the npm package is with dash -> reference - https://github.com/NimperX/react-aws-s3-typescript/blob/main/src/Url.ts. Thanks for another suggestion.